# I wanted to understand the chess engine comparison. What does this result matrix show?

Tags: engines

[image]

For example in the first row and second column, Stockfish vs Houdini, the result is 27-25+7-3=-16. I understand that 27 signifies Stockfish's number of wins+ draws, similarly 25 signifies that of Houdini. But what does "7-3" signify? and how is the result -16?

And what does the blank in Row 1, column 7 mean? similarly in (6,11), (7,1), (7,10), (7, 12), (10,7), (11,6), (11, 12), (12,7), (12,11). Do they signify that those matchups have never happened? If so Where should I look for if I want comparison of such matchups?

This question may be weird, but please at least guide me where should I ask these questions if not the answer.

Comment: A partial answer: The first row in each cell gives the match result in points (1 point for a win, 0.5 for a draw, 0 for a loss), the second row gives the games' results: 7 wins, 3 losses, 40 draws. You should ask the publisher of this table for further details.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I'm very stupid to not see it. As for the publisher, I tried to make an account in ccrl forum, but the registration captcha is too tough, which I failed 12 times and counting. Any idea why the result of 7 wins 3 losses and 40 draws is -16?

Comment: They are rating performance. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@muclux is right on the results. Check his comment. I'll answer what "16" mean.

Scroll further down on the page.

[image]

The number is the **rating change**. Stockfish lost 16 rating point to Houdini, similarly Houdini won 16 points from Stockfish (convince yourself by going to the Houdini vs Stockfish cell).

Comment: Thanks, just want to confirm, you are talking about elo rating, right?

Comment: @Rajesh381 I'm not sure how CCRl rating work. Send them an email?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer to the meaning of the numbers is at the top of the list above that matrix.

[image: column descriptions]
As for the blank spots, yes I believe those are for games which did not occur.

Comment: I don't follow, I thought that few lines above the table are the conditions under which the games were recorded

Comment: No, the first one is a list, the other is just the top twelve counted and put into a matrix.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but there's no explanation of how the result is calculated and filled in matrix. I mean what does the -16 in the photo I posted signify?

Comment: oh, sorry I misunderstood that part.